# ngFor directive template rendering for ajax request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

post service file

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class PostService {

    private  url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
    constructor(private _http: Http) {

    }

    getData() {
        return this._http.get(this.url)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

---

app.component.ts

app component uses the the post service(above) to retreive some data and i would like to render in the page.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
///<reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
import {PostService} from './post.service';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:`

          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#item of items"> {{item.title}} </li>
          </ul>  
          `,
    providers:[PostService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})
export class AppComponent {

    items = [];

    constructor(private  postService: PostService){

        this.postService.getData()
            .subscribe(function (data) {
                this.items = data;
            });
    }
}
```

It doesn't give any error but also it does not render, can somebody help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Problem I see is:

```
<li *ngFor="#item of items">
```

Assuming you are using version rc.1 (the latest version as of today 5/11/16), the correct syntax for this would be:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">
```

Also, this might not be the problem but your 'subscribe' chunk of code is a little different than I usually do mine.

Yours:

```
        this.postService.getData()
        .subscribe(function (data) {
            this.items = data;
        });
```

How I would do it:

```
    this.postService.getData()
        .subscribe(
            data => this.items = data,
            error => alert(error),
            () => console.log("Subscribed")
    )};
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe # is syntactic sugar for let, so both are the same(tested on rc1 version). But the problem was the callback as you pointed out. If i turn into arrow function it works but not as a function(). That is very strange to me. Maybe it is about scoping but not sure. Can somebody explain?